# Simplest way to setup an XHR endpoint in WordPress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, email

I'm porting a client site from a vanilla PHP setup to WordPress. They have a `/mail/send.php` script and the script just sends an email with `mail()`. That URL is hit with a jQuery `$.ajax` request.

I'm not sure, however, how to just hit that URL or a new URL that executes that simple `mail()` line. The examples I'm seeing online don't seem very simple and require route overrides or multiple files to setup. Is there a way to do this in like one function or something?

Comment: Did you check [this article](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)?

Comment: @LukaPeharda is that related? That says it's specifically for "plugin developers, describes how to add Ajax to a plugin. "

Comment: Yes, nevermind that it says for plugin developers. You can reuse this in a theme that you are building.